# Force the Browser Mode and Document Mode of IE 9 to IE 9

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I need to force both the browser mode and document mode of my IE 9 to IE 9. Now, I've set "X-UA-Compatible" to "IE=9" in the  tag of my header, but it has no effect when I change the document mode to either IE 7 / IE 8.

[image: Force the Browser Mode and Document Mode of IE 9 to IE 9]

My site  is to be compatible only with IE 9 and not with any other versions of IE. Furthermore, I looked through and studied most questions answered here and through blogs (msdn) but nothing seems to be working for me (Before the moderators close this as a duplicate question). Can any one of you guide me about the same ?

Comment: you can learn more about that at on the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325\(v=VS.85\).aspx), but I don't see why it won't change the compatibility on your page...

Comment: that's what is bothering me too...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IF you have set up the (X-UA..") tags already then that should force it into the appropriate Document Mode and Browser Mode.

It looks like you're setting the document mode in the IE dev tools console, this overrides it whatever you put in as tags.

[This diagram explains how IE determines what modes to display in and the dev toolbar takes priority.](http://ieblog.members.winisp.net/misc/How%20IE9%20Determines%20Document%20Mode.svg)

Edit/Update

Unfortunately it seems the above link got taken down. [For now here is an alternative](http://web.archive.org/web/20100924025133/http://ieblog.members.winisp.net/misc/How%20IE9%20Determines%20Document%20Mode.svg)

Answer (score 10):

Well,
Make Sure The tag ("X-UA-...") you are putting should be the first tag inside the Header of your document. Secondly, verify that the html renders (by view source property) in browser, also contains as the first tag ("X-UA-...") in header section.

Comment: Voting this one up, because it includes the important piece of information I was missing: Make sure the following tag is the FIRST tag inside your `<head>` tag: `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />`